# Delphi 7 | Deleting only a char from a edit.text

Tags: delphi

I need help creating a code to a button, where this button deletes only a char from an edit.text, imagine I have a text "daniel" and by pressing my created button it deletes "l", to become "danie".

Comment: Do you need to delete specific char or the last char?

Comment: Check out `System.Delete()`

Comment: Last char @AlexCode

Comment: @TomBrunberg I have seen it, feels like `System.Delete()` will only delete a specific char, I need to delete the last one typed

Comment: @DanielDias `System.Delete()` lets you specify a starting index and number of chars to delete from that index.

Comment: @DanielDias you have to said that from the very beginning... It's another story to delete the last or first char and another what you asked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Delete` procedure in the `System` unit, and use `Length(s)` to specify the last character of the string:

```
procedure TForm24.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := Edit1.Text;
  Delete(s, Length(s), 1);
  Edit1.Text := s;
end;
```

Alternatively you can use the `Copy()` function:

```
procedure TForm24.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := copy(Edit1.Text, 1, Length(Edit1.Text)-1);
end;
```

Comment: I used it, worked perfectly, thanks for spending time helping me out ,thumbs up :)

Comment: Don't use `Button2Click`; the others are fine!

Comment: The others change the state of the Windows edit control once; `Button2` does it thrice. You might even see visible flickering when the selection is created.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SelStart` and `SelLength` properties to select the desired text, and then use the `SelText` property to remove the selected text:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Len: Integer; 
begin
  Len := Edit1.GetTextLen;
  If Len > 0 then
  begin
    Edit1.SelStart := Len-1;
    Edit1.SelLength := 1;
    Edit1.SelText := '';
  end; 
end;
```

This has the benefit of not needing to allocate any memory to retrieve the actual `Text` content, alter it, and assign it back to the `Text` property.  Everything is done inside the control's own internal buffer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var
  beforeStr, afterStr : string;

begin
  // Try to replace all occurrences for example of letter l
  beforeStr := 'Daniel';

  afterStr := StringReplace(beforeStr , 'l', '',
                          [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  ShowMessage('beforeStr = '+beforeStr);
  ShowMessage('afterStr = '+afterStr );
end;
```

*`rfReplaceAll` flag is if you want to replace all the occurrences.

Comment: Of course, that's an example of how to do what you want, put whatever character and from whatever string to replace it with whatever you need.

Comment: What if beforeStr is 'LOL'?